# Certain functions in YouTube AS3 API return wrong values

Tags: actionscript-3, api, youtube

I'm now working on a certain AS3 application. The code is pretty much the AS3 example from the documentation:

```
// The player SWF file on www.youtube.com needs to communicate with your host
// SWF file. Your code must call Security.allowDomain() to allow this
// communication.
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

// This will hold the API player instance once it is initialized.;
var player:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void
{
    stage.addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void
{
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the Player API ID 
    trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);

    // Once this event has been dispatched by the player, we can use
    // cueVideoById, loadVideoById, cueVideoByUrl and loadVideoByUrl
    // to load a particular YouTube video.
    player = loader.content;
    player.loadVideoById("nJ3MSCLBpaM");
    // Set appropriate player dimensions for your application;
    setPlayerSize();
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, updatePlayerSize);
}

function setPlayerSize():void
{
    player.y = 0;
    player.x = 0;
    player.setSize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}

function getVideoBytesTotal()
{
    return player.getVideoBytesTotal();
}
function getVideoBytesLoaded()
{
    return player.getVideoBytesLoaded();
}
function getVideoStartBytes()
{
    return player.getVideoStartBytes();
}
```

for some reason, when I call one of the last three functions after the video has loaded (and while it is playing) all I get is 0, from all of them. Why is that?

Comment: I've noticed it only happens in firefox. Chrome works well.

Comment: Actually I'm running on Chrome and it's not working. :O

Comment: does this test works to you?  http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player

Comment: that's using the JS API. I'm working in AS.

Comment: It's using as3 when I'm checking.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are deprecated.
Use

```
player.getVideoLoadedFraction()
```

instead.